# How to know if HuggingFace's pipeline text input exceeds 512 tokens

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I've finetuned a Huggingface BERT model for Named Entity Recognition based on `'bert-base-uncased'`. I perform inference like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline
ner_pipeline = pipeline('token-classification', model=model_folder, tokenizer=model_folder)
out = ner_pipeline(text, aggregation_strategy='simple')
```

I want to obtain results on very long texts, and since I know of the 512 token maximum capacity for both training and inference, I split my `text`s in smaller chunks before passing those to the `ner_pipeline`.

But, how do I split the text without actually tokenizing the texts myself in order to check for the length of each chunk? I want to make them as long as possible, but at the same time I don't want to exceed the maximum 512 tokens, risking that no predictions are computed on what's left of the sentence.

Is there a way to know if the texts I'm feeding exceed the 512 maximum tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding out whether tokenized text exceeds 512 tokens is simply checking its tokenized output. For this purpose, you can simply use `AutoTokenizer` library of [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoTokenizer). For example,

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
sentence = "Sentence to check whether it exceeds 512 tokens"

tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)

print(len(sentence.split()))  # here is the default length of the sentence
print(len(tokenized_sentence)) # here is the tokenized length
```

You can give it a try for long documents and observe that at some points tokenized lengths exceed 512 tokens. This may not be a problem for text classification but you may lose your entity labels for the token classification task. Thus, before feeding your Transformer-based network with long documents, you should preprocess your texts with `AutoTokenizer`, find the points where the tokenized texts reach the maximum length of the model input size (e.g, 512), and simply cut the sentence from that point and create a new sample from the remaining part of that long document.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar indeed. I expected to find a less "hacky" way, but I guess this is it.